# Get last inserted value from MySQL using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, declarative

I want to return the last inserted value for an auto_increment field in MySQL.

I have seen examples that mention the use of `session.flush()` to add the record and then retrieve the id.  However that always seems to return 0.

I have also seen examples that mention the use of session.refresh() but that raises the following error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Could not refresh instance '<MyModel....>'
```

My code looks something like this:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tblfoo'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine':'InnoDB'}

    ModelID = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), default=0, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    ModelName = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=True, index=True)
    ModelMemo = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=True)

f = Foo(ModelName='Bar', ModelMemo='Foo')
session.add(f)
session.flush()
```

At this point, the object f has been pushed to the DB, and has been automatically assigned a unique primary key id.  However, I can't seem to find a way to obtain the value to use in some additional operations.  I would like to do the following:

my_new_id = f.ModelID

I know I could simply execute another query to lookup the ModelID based on other parameters but I would prefer not to if at all possible.

Comment: The `insert` syntax for postgresql has a `insert ( ... ) returning myindex`, feature, which allows you to return your named index in the same way a select query would return it.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17764794/445131

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is you are setting `defaul` for the auto increment. So when it run the insert into query the log of server is

```
2011-12-21 13:44:26,561 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...1150 INSERT INTO tblfoo (`ModelID`, `ModelName`, `ModelMemo`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
2011-12-21 13:44:26,561 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...1150 (0, 'Bar', 'Foo')
ID : 0
```

So the output is `0` which is the default value and which is passed because you are setting default value for `autoincrement` column.

If I run same code without `default` then it give the correct output.

Please try this code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://test:test@localhost/test1', echo=True)

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = Session()

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Unicode

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tblfoo'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine':'InnoDB'}

    ModelID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    ModelName = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=True, index=True)
    ModelMemo = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

f = Foo(ModelName='Bar', ModelMemo='Foo')
session.add(f)
session.flush()

print "ID :", f.ModelID
```

Comment: Nice catch, didn't notice the default=0.

Comment: Ugh...yes, nice catch.  My head was in the SQL world where a default value is required for a primary key field when you create the table.  Thanks for the find.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `session.commit()` instead of `session.flush()`. You can then use `f.ModelID`.

Comment: I tried it after both the flush and commit but received the following error:  AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Sorry, updated the answer to use ModelID like you used into your schema declaration. Still, you should probably use `id` instead of `ModelID`.

Comment: Sadly, I've tried that approach many ways and continue to get the following error: ObjectDeletedError: Instance '<Foo at 0x397d190>' has been deleted.

Comment: `flush()` is suppose to clear the transaction, that's why I'm suggesting a `commit()`. If that doesn't work, I'm lost then.

Comment: If I use commit() then I get the following error: ObjectDeletedError: Instance '<Foo at 0x3240a10>' has been deleted.  If I only use flush() then the value is 0, the default value not the actual inserted value for the record.

Comment: In an attempt to align my code with your suggestion I changed the field name of the ID field to id.  If I run this:  
                con.add(f)
                con.flush()
                print f.id

I now receive a different error:  ConcurrentModificationError: Updated rowcount 0 does not match number of objects updated 1

I am really confused now...

Comment: In my case i was closing the session before get the inserted object ID, just swaped lines.  it worked

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the flagged answer worked for you. But in my case, that does not actually insert the row into the table. I need to call `commit()` in the end.

So the last few lines of code are:

```
f = Foo(ModelName='Bar', ModelMemo='Foo')
session.add(f)
session.flush()

print "ID:", f.ModelID

session.commit()
```