# How to get inserted_primary_key from db.engine.connect().execute call

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I'm using:

```
CPython 2.7.3,
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==0.16
psycopg2==2.5.1
and
postgresql-9.2
```

Trying to get PK from insert call with alchemy.

Getting engine like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar('SOME_VAR')
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)  # Fix for old proxyes

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And executing insert query in app:

```
    from sqlalchemy import text, exc
    def query():
        return db.engine.connect().execute(text('''
        insert into test...'''), kw)
    rv = query()
```

But trying access `inserted_primary_key` property, get:

```
InvalidRequestError: Statement is not an insert() expression construct.
```

How to enable implicit_returning in my case, reading the docs doesn't help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `RETURNING` clause and handle this yourself:

```
INSERT INTO test (...) VALUES (...) RETURNING id
```

Then you can retrieve the id as you normally retrieve values from queries.

Note that this works on Postgres, but does not work on other db engines like MySQL or sqlite.

I don't think there is a db agnostic way to do this within SQLAlchemy without using the ORM functionality.

Comment: For mysql - result.lastrowid

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Postgresql, tried everything, like `lastrowid` (does't work, always return 0), your solution is the only one that works for me

Answer (score 5):

Is there any reason you do text query instead of normal sqlalchemy insert()? If you're using sqlalchemy it will probably be much easier for you to rephrase your query into:

```
from sqlalchemy import text, exc, insert

# in values you can put dictionary of keyvalue pairs
# key is the name of the column, value the value to insert
con = db.engine.connect()
ins = tablename.insert().values(users="frank")
res = con.execute(ins)
res.inserted_primary_key
[1]
```

This way sqlalchemy will do the binding for you.

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to use raw SQL. Is there any way to shove ' implicit_returning=True engine kw' to flask-sqlalchemy?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can get it if you use raw sql, but if you do alchemy insert(), it works ok, I've edited my answer to show this.

Comment: I like raw SQL and do not whant to declare my schema second time in python code. All what I whant is get PK id after insert with db.engine.connect().execute('''raw sql insert here'''

Comment: @greggyNapalm: "do not whant to declare my schema second time in python code", Just for the record, you don't need to declare your schema in Python. There is reflection and you can work directly with tables.

Comment: @greggyNapalm did you ever get to this to work with raw SQL?  (I am coming across this same problem 8 years after you.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use lastrowid

```
rv = query()
rv.lastrowid
```